# Algorithm computing a set of teams guaranteed to win the tournament

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have been working on the algorithm for this problem, but can't figure it out. The problem is below:

There are n teams competing in the tournament. After each game, the loser is removed from the tournament, and the winner continues without having to play in the next game. 2 teams play with each other at a time until there is one team left, which will be the winner.

We are also given some pairs of teams in the set E, such that pair `(i,j)` means team `i` will beat team `j`. The pairs in set `E` do not cover all possible matches and are not transitive (team `i` beats team `j`, and team `j` beats team `k` does not mean team `i` beats team `k`)

We need to find an `O(n + |E|)` time algorithm to compute a set of teams `A`, so that for each team `i` in `A`, there exists a possible schedule where team `i` is guaranteed to win the tournament.

Comment: what do you mean by "winner continues without having to play in the next game". In this situation there will be no tournament winner at all because the final game won't start.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious I guess it means that the winning team might pass the next round if the number of teams in that next round is odd. Or maybe, simply in any round the scheduler is free to schedule matches and promote automatically the teams he would like to. It needs clarification

Comment: @CsIsFun is your idea to start with?

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious Sorry for the ambiguity. That means the winning team in a game remains in the tournament, but doesn't necessarily play in the next game. Let's say it can play after 2 or 3 games between other teams.

Comment: @A.S.H Please read the clarification above

Comment: @A.S.H Don't think there are any "rounds" in the tournament specification. And even if they were, doesn't matter how many teams are in this round, they all are either winners or haven't played yet.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious Yes, from what i understood in the OP's clarification, the scheduler is totally free in scheduling the games. The only requirement is to continue playing until there is only one winner.

Comment: @CsIsFun And you need to get any set A, or maximum possible set A?

Comment: getting any A with one element (and a proven schedule) seems already to be a challenge, dont you think?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Tarajan's strongly connected components alghorithm` task.

Consider the set of teams is `V` and the set if directed edges is `E`. Direction corresponds to the wining team.

The component is strongly connected if every vertex in this component is reachable from other vertex of this component. This means that every team in this component can win among every other team from this component, because you can schedule games as you want. So each team from such component is either in A or neither of them are in A. So you may think of each such component as a single "large team". That algorithm finds all such components, so finally you have a directed graph of "large teams" without strongly connected components, so you have an order on this graph.

Now you take every "large team" that has no parents. That means that noone can guarantee to beat this large team. Let's call this set as "strongest teams" (again this is the set of strongly connected components of original graph). This can be done in linear time because you just traverse graph. Now if the "strongest teams" has more then one "large team" then you can't guarantee winner. Otherwise it has only single "large team" which is your set A.

Note that `Tarajan's strongly connected components alghorithm` runs as
 `O(|V| + |E|)`, so in your case it's `O(n + |E|)` and traversing the "large team" graph is `O(n)` so this is how you find A with `O(n + |E|)`.